# find the limits $\lim_{n} f(a_n)=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n= \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x+x\lfloor x\rfloor}{x\cos x -x}$
> then :
>
> $$\lim_{n} f(a_n)=?$$

---

My Try :

$$a_n= (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}})=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} $$

$$f(a_n)=\dfrac{\sin (a_n)+a_n\lfloor a_n\rfloor}{a_n\cos(a_n) -a_n}$$

now what?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? Does $a_n$ have a limit?

Answer (score 2):

Forget about $f$ for a moment. Multiply $a_n$ by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ in both numerator and denominator, to conclude that $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$, which clearly goes to 0. Now just apply l'Hopital's rule to $f(x)$ with $x\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Observe that $0 \le a_n < 1$ for $n \ge 1$. Consequently, $\lfloor a_n \rfloor =0$. As such,
$$f(a_n) = \frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos(a_n)-1}$$

Comment: thanks a lot . thaus Answer is $-\infty$ is it right ?

Comment: Yes, the answer is $-\infty$.